# UPDATE field of last entry SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I like to update the field "filepath" of my table "imagedata" of the last entry made?

```
UPDATE `imagedata` SET `filepath`='sdsd' WHERE `id` = MAX(imagedata.id);
```

Somehow my synax ist not right it says:

```
Invalid use of group function`
```

what do i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an AUTO_INCREMENT column, You could try

```sql
UPDATE `imagedata` SET `filepath`='sdsd' WHERE `id` = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: What do you think will `LAST_INSERT_ID()` return if you have 2 or more tables with auto_increment?

Comment: Also, from [MySQL docs, LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id): *"The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a **per-connection** basis."* What if you want to just connect to the database and run the Update?

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE `imagedata` 
SET `filepath`='sdsd' 
order by id desc limit 1
```

Another alternative:

```
UPDATE `imagedata` 
SET `filepath`='sdsd' 
where id = (select * from (select max(id) from imagedata) as t)
```

Comment: firts one works! greate :) second one works as well. I had it like UPDATE `imagedata` 
SET `filepath`='sdsdffff' 
where id = (select max(id) from imagedata)  before but this dont do it it says:You can't specify target table 'imagedata' for update in FROM clause